# Mongo collection.find().then() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I can do this, no problem

```
myCollection.findOne({_id:"1234"})
    .then(function(element){

    });
```

But I cannot do this

```
myCollection.find()
    .then(function(element){

    });
```

Because apparently

> TypeError: myCollection.find(...).then is not a function

Comment: Because it returns a "Cursor" and not a Promise. You probably want `find().toArray().then(...)`. There is actually [documentation for this.](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#find)

Comment: I was stuck with the same problem, thanks for doing this quesiton.